# Error trying to deplay a strapi app to heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, strapi

I am getting this error in the console when trying to deploy

`"https://npm.fontawesome.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/-/5.15.4/fontawesome-free-5.15.4.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\""`

I'm not using font awesome anywhere in the project. Has anyone seen this?